# How can I count how many divs whose ids begin with a certain text that are inside a div using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's the html:

```
<div class="col-sm-12" id="ProdutosPedido">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 formProdutoAdd" id="produto_1">
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As things happen within the page, divs are appended inside `#ProdutosPedido`, and `#produto_1` increments to `#produto_2` and so on.

This is not working for me:

```
console.log($("#ProdutosPedido > [id^=produto_]").length);
```

I need to iterate over these "produto_" and use the 'i' to refer to the current div, but I don't know how to do it. My example logs 0, and that should not be the case, since it starts with 1.

Comment: `id="produto_1"` is not a direct child

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your `produto` divs are not direct children of `ProdutosPedido`, but its descendants, you need to use the following selector:

```
$("#ProdutosPedido [id^=produto_]")
```

Here is the working [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ykurmangaliyev/4sm3q52n/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Pure Javascript Solution

```
function CountDiv() {
            var nodes = document.getElementById('ProdutosPedido').getElementsByTagName('*');
            var Count = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {                
                if (nodes[i].id.substring(0, 8) == 'produto_')
                    Count++;
            }
            alert(Count);
        }
```